# Is there a programmatic way to access and retrieve data from the Google Admin Dashboard Settings?

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-workspace, google-directory-api

Is there any way to get the settings data from Google Admin Dashboard. I have a list of policies that need to be satisfied with this.
I've already gone through Google's documentation for Workspace Admin SDK and none of the settings are exposed. Seems as though Google doesn't expose their settings API. I know scraping and then verifying is a possibility but are there any other methods that could be followed to get these settings.
Some examples of the policies include:

- Ensure login challenges are enforced
- Ensure Google session control is configured
- Ensure only authorized third-party applications are allowed

All of these policies are configurable through the UI. But I need a way to programmatically find out whether these settings are configured as they should be.

Comment: Currently all of the settings you have mentioned is unavailable, and on a personal note, it would impose a security risk since all of the settings you have mentioned leans on the security features of the Admin Console. But I would suggest, you can submit a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191635&template=824102) so that Google may consider adding this feature on Admin SDK.

Comment: I see. I have submitted a feature request but is there any way aside REST APIs to get the details?